# Click event on one control sometimes does not fire

Tags: vba, excel, click, controls

I have two buttons on a sheet.  On occasion, clicking on one of the buttons does not "fire" the event.

- Floating the cursor over the button changes the cursor from a cross to an arrow
- The button does not appear to "depress" as it would if the event fired.
- Breakpoint or Stop statement in the code do not get reached.
- The other button never demonstrates this problem.
- If the code is started manually, the code will run as designed.
- In `Designer Mode`, the code appears to be attached to the button.
- Closing and re-opening the worksheet, and then triggering the button that normally works will restore functionality to this button.

Trouble shooting advice would be appreciated.
The button code is below as is the properties window, but I think the problem lies elsewhere; just don't know where to look.

Again, another very similar button, which calls different code, seems to work OK all the time.

Thanks for any guidance.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cbDeleteViewed_Click()
With cbDeleteViewed
    .Width = .Width
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Select Case Environ("COMPUTERNAME")
        Case "RON-DODIER"
            sDrive = "F:\"
            sBasePath = "Videos"
            ProtectDisable Sheet1
            UnProtectEnable Sheet3
            Sheet3.Select
        Case "RONBP"
            sDrive = "Z:\"
            sBasePath = ""
            ProtectDisable Sheet3
            UnProtectEnable Sheet1
            Sheet1.Select
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Cannot Run on This Computer"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
SetUpZ
DeleteViewedShows

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You have one button which you say works consistently and one which does not. I would try modifying one of the buttons properties and its code slowly bit-by-bit to the properties/code of the other until you see the same behavior as the other button. Then you will know that the last change you made is likely the cause.

Comment: @garb Thanks.  I have made changes in the properties during a time when the button was not working, but it didn't seem to help.  But I will try that again when it malfunctions again.  So far as the code, the difference has to do with the macro that is being called within the code.  And also, I have been using this workbook for years, and it has only started misbehaving in the past few weeks (with no relevant changes that I can think of).

Comment: did you try cleaning the old exd files? Worth an attempt. Also for these sudden irregularities, alot ot times, office updates are the culprit.

Comment: @cyboashu Yes, the last time it happened, I did clean the old exd files.  Didn't make a difference. And, again, only this button was not working.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I was referring to the `Locked` property in Userform controls. (BTW, just as a friendly hint: I don't understand why you are assigning `.Width = .Width` to the identical value).

Comment: @T.M. Yes, I thought you might be referring to a different type of object.  So far as the `Width`, I was having a problem with the object changing size after the click event, and this seemed to control that.